# Change State and City of Standard Lead Address Fields to Custom Dependent Picklists

Tags: apex, sales, address

We are using the standard Address field on Lead currently, while sales manager complains users input various wrong data for State and City in either English or local language, and he wants to replace State and City with restricted dependent picklists to ensure data accuracy.

The most similar out-of-box approach I've found is Salesforce State and Country Picklists, which does not really meet the requirement as it doesn't support City level.

Considering Lead conversion, the solution I could come up with minimum efforts is:

1. Create custom fields for each Address element (Zip Code, Street, City, State and Country), with State and City as dependent picklists and others as free text.
2. Replace standard Address field with custom fields on layouts.
3. Build automation to populate standard Address field with custom field values.
4. Update all historical data.

But I'm just wondering if this is the best solution. Is there any easier way to achieve this?

Comment: Seems legit approach to me (no sarcasm here).

Comment: How many State and City values will you have?  You should check the picklist field limits and dependency limits in the documentation.  Also the dependency input matrix becomes extremely cumbersome to use when you have many values in it.

Comment: Thank you both for your advise. I will check the documents and ensure feasibility again.